# Definition of type-hint in laravel documentation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel document says

> Of course, you may also **type-hint** any Laravel contract. If the
>   container can resolve it, you can **type-hint** it.

So what is the meaning of type-hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an object via the container, it will try to resolve its dependencies that are represented by your object's constructor arguments. However, container needs to know what type of the dependency is, that's why you need to type-hint the arguments, meaning you need to define the type of the arguments, e.g.:

```
public function __construct(Hasher $hasher) {
  //some logic
}
```

In the above example I've type-hinted the $hasher argument - I told the container that it should pass an object of type Hasher.

Apart from type-hinting class names you can also type-hint an interface. Contracts in Laravel are interfaces that are implemented by Laravel's concrete classes. This is useful if you do not care about what specific class will be passed as long as it implements given interface.

With contracts, the example above could look like that:

```
public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher) {
  //some logic
}
```